# Turn Rows and Columns Into Table With Headers By Default

Tags: excel

How to make by default excel rows and columns to become in table with headers ? For example every time I open new excel with data I turn it into table with headers manually by clicking `Data` -> `From Text`. How to make it to open all files by default in the same way, not to make it manually ?

I want this:

[image]

To become this by default:

[image]

Comment: what is the file extension? could you use some code?

Comment: The file extension is CSV

Answer (score 0):

Choice of delimiter (list separator) : Comma or Tab or Semicolon

Use tab or comma to check what happens. Actually, you have to check list separator setting in your regional setting.

for detail : [superuser link](https://superuser.com/questions/238944/how-to-force-excel-to-open-csv-files-with-data-arranged-in-columns)